# Split mulitple part of string in some html div with id

Tags: javascript, string, split, multiline

HI i need to split some part of variable value

in my html file i got a dynamic value of variable some thing like this

```
product/roe_anythin_anything-1.jpg 

product/soe_anything_anything-2.jpg
```

i need to remove the before

> /slashpart

and after

> _ part

which should return the `roe or soe` part

i have use a function

```
  <script>
function splitSize(){

$('#splitSize').each(function(index) {
    var mystr = $(this).html();
    var mystr1 = /product\/(.*)-.*/.exec(mystr);
    $(this).html(mystr1[1]);
    //$(this).html(mystr1[0]);  
});
}
splitSize();


</script>
```

with which i got roe_anythin_anything successfully i just need to remove now after `

> _ part

`

please suggest how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

This is as you asked using split . You can use RegEx to make it simpler

```
 var myStr = 'product/roe-1.jpg' ;
 myStr = myStr.split('/')[1];
 myStr = myStr.split('-')[0];
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwXU3/)

Comment: Or with an regular expression in one line: `myStr.split(/\/|-/)[1];` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCUB8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex group capture

```
var myStr = 'product/roe-1.jpg';
var result = /product\/(.*)-.*/.exec(myStr)[1];
```

Break down:

```
/product\/
```

matches the initial product string and the / character (escaped so its not interpreted as the end of the regex)

The

```
(.*)
```

Matches your roe characters and keeps them in a 'capture group' - everything up to but not including the hyphen

Then the hyphen is matched, then anything else.

This returns a 2 element array.  Item 0 is the whole string, item 1 is the contents of the capture group.

See [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) for more details

Comment: this is my string  product/tammy_av_pewter-1_1.jpg   byusing your i got 
tammy_av_pewter  how to remove _av_pewter  also   but thanks for now help